# php Простое объявление Класса. Откуда берутся Warning?

Tags: php, классы

Объясните, пожалуйста, есть вот такой элементарный код [создания класса](https://onlinephp.io/c/851d69)

```
<?php

class Person {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    
    public function sayHi(){
        echo "Hello, my name is ". $this->$name . " and I'm ". $this->$age ."yars old";
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->name = "Alex";
$person->age = 19;

$person->sayHi();
```

Почему и как избавиться от Warning при компиляции кода?

Comment: `$this->$name` => `$this->name`; `$this->$age` => `$this->age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дам простой пример.

`$this->$name` означает, что вы хотите обратиться к полю объекта с помощью какой-то локальной переменной. Например:

```php
$name = 'user';
echo $this->$name
```

это будет то же самое, если

```php
echo $this->user
```

Но у вас в методе sayHi нет ни `$name`, ни `$age`